# Couldn't determine repo type for URL: `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/admin/.netrc React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cocoapods, pod-install

When I am installing pod it shows me this error, I've tried reinstalling cocoapods and an older version of react native just to make sure if it's version issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved, it was a permission issue in every file on my MacBook. I used `sudo chown -R macbook-name: /yourfilepath`. Use this command whenever you faced permission-denied errors.